# Classification method for biased training data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining

I am trying to use patent texts to make a binary classification of a large number of patents as either 1. related to automation or 2. not related to automation.

I have manually classified a small non-random subset of patents and would like to use them to train a classifier. I formed this subset by looking at all firms that had patented an automation technology in a small window of time. Non-automation patents in the subset are thus going to be quite different than non-automation patents in the whole data because they are filed by firms that do some work in automation.

My question has two parts:

1. Is there a classification method that can be used with "biased" training data? (My hunch is no but never hurts to ask.)
2. Alternatively, is there a classification method that will simply identify which patent texts are most like the ones I classified as automation patents?

Comment: This might help or might obviate your project. Patents are already classified by the patent office. There is a rich classification system based on what is claimed in a patent. Actually there are multiple systems. In the newish CPC system the major class G05B includes CONTROL OR REGULATING SYSTEMS IN GENERAL; FUNCTIONAL ELEMENTS OF SUCH SYSTEMS; . . . " . Sub-classes include G05B 13/00 "Adaptive control systems . .  performance which is optimum according to some preassigned criterion".